# Why the limit of the weak convergence is the same as the limit of strong convergence for the same sequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Why the limit of the weak convergence is the same as the limit of strong convergence  for the same sequence?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges strongly to $x$ and weakly to $y$. Then for each bounded linear functional $\ell$, $\ell(x_n)\to \ell(y)$ by definition of weak convergence. Moreover, $\lvert \ell(x_n)-\ell(x)\rvert=\lvert \ell(x_n-x) \rvert\leqslant \lVert \ell\rVert \lVert x_n-x\rVert$ hence $\ell(x_n)\to \ell(x)$. Therefore, for each bounded linear functional $\ell$, $\ell(x-y)=0$. Now, define a linear functional $L$ on the vector space generated by $x-y$ by $L(c(x-y))=c\lVert x-y\rVert$ and extend it by Hahn-Banach theorem to get that $x=y$.

Comment: Is it there any simpler proof?

Comment: I don't now: the best that we can deduce directly from both convergences is that their difference is in the kernel of all linear continuous functional. But then in order to show that this intersection of kernel is reduced to $0$, we need some stuff.

Comment: Can we say that this is correct by the second part of  the following theorem "Let $X$ be a normed linear space . Then every weakly convergent sequence in $X$ is bounded. Moreover, if $\{x_{n}\}\rightharpoonup in X, $ then $$\|x\| \leq lim inf \|x_{n}\|$$  "